# Displaying gaps on charts in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm using `XYChart` in JavaFX 8 and I would like to display gaps for empty cells for the specified series. When I passed *null* value then I got `NullPointerException`:

```
series.get(index).getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(Key, null));
```

I also found the bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092134 describing this problem, but I don't know is it still actual.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Best regards,

Michael

Comment: I was doing some basic searching regarding your recently asked question about a socket-using Swing chat application , but the question was deleted before I could post my comments, so if you don't mind, I will post them here. It appears that what you're looking for is a responsive socket-based Swing chat application, one that can send messages out via a socket and read them back in via a socket withouto breaking down or freezing up. Fortunately, such applications have been written before and questions about them abound on this site.

Comment: I invite you to check out these answers to similar questions: [MadProgrammer answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44158305/), [MadProgrammer answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70647587/),  [Hovercraft answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51178338/), and [Google search for similar questions on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+jtextarea+chat+socket+swingworker).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is quite evident that, this feature is not included.. and if you are very desperate to get this behavior, you can try the below logic.

Having said that, there can be many better ways, but this answer is to give you some initial idea about how you can tweak the current implementation using the protected methods of the chart.

The idea is.. once the plot children layout is done, we recompute the logic of rendering the line path.. and remove the unwanted data points. And as mentioned, this is just for idea purpose only, if you have more data series, then you may need to work accordingly.

**[UPDATE] :** If you want the paths/data points for each series, append the ".series" to the ".chart-series-line" and ".data" style classes.

Please check the below demo:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.PathElement;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.*;

public class XYChartDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("days");
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setLabel("USD");

        // AS OF NOW THIS IS THE CORE POINT I AM RELYING ON !! YOU CAN THINK OF A BETTER APPROACH TO IDENTIFY THE GAP POINTS.
        List<Integer> s0GapIndexes = Arrays.asList(3, 7);
        List<Integer> s1GapIndexes = Arrays.asList(4, 8);

        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> seriesGap = new HashMap<>();
        seriesGap.put(0, s0GapIndexes);
        seriesGap.put(1, s1GapIndexes);
        XYChart.Series<String, Double> series0 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series0.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-01", 13.2));
        series0.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-02", 10.1));
        series0.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-03", 14.1));
        series0.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-04", 0.0)); // gap (INDEX 3)
        series0.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-05", 6.3));
        series0.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-06", 9.82));
        series0.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-07", 12.82));
        series0.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-08", 0.0)); // gap (INDEX 7)
        series0.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-09", 4.82));
        series0.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-10", 8.82));
        series0.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-11", 8.82));

        XYChart.Series<String, Double> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series1.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-01", 20.2));
        series1.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-02", 14.1));
        series1.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-03", 7.1));
        series1.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-04", 9.0));
        series1.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-05", 0.0)); // gap (INDEX 4)
        series1.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-06", 5.32));
        series1.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-07", 11.0));
        series1.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-08", 15.3));
        series1.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-09", 0.0)); // gap (INDEX 8)
        series1.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-10", 4.82));
        series1.getData().add(new Data<>("2000-01-11", 6.82));

        CustomLineChart lineChart = new CustomLineChart(xAxis, yAxis, seriesGap);
        lineChart.getData().addAll(series0, series1);
        root.getChildren().addAll(lineChart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class CustomLineChart<X, Y> extends LineChart<X, Y> {

        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> seriesGap;

        public CustomLineChart(Axis<X> xAxis, Axis<Y> yAxis, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> seriesGap) {
            super(xAxis, yAxis);
            this.seriesGap = seriesGap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutPlotChildren() {
            super.layoutPlotChildren();
            updatePath();
            updateDataPoints();
        }

        private void updatePath() {
            seriesGap.forEach((seriesNo, gapIndexes) -> {
                Path path = (Path) lookup(".chart-series-line.series" + seriesNo);
                System.out.println(path);
                if (!path.getElements().isEmpty()) {
                    int dataSize = getData().get(seriesNo).getData().size();
                    int pathEleSize = path.getElements().size();
                    // Just ensuring we are dealing with right path
                    if (pathEleSize == dataSize + 1) {
                        // Build a new path, by jumping the gap points
                        List<PathElement> newPath = new ArrayList<>();
                        newPath.add(path.getElements().get(0));
                        for (int i = 1; i < path.getElements().size(); i++) {
                            if (gapIndexes.contains(i - 1)) {
                                LineTo lt = (LineTo) path.getElements().get(i + 1);
                                newPath.add(new MoveTo(lt.getX(), lt.getY()));
                            } else {
                                newPath.add(path.getElements().get(i));
                            }
                        }

                        // Update the new path to the current path.
                        path.getElements().clear();
                        path.getElements().addAll(newPath);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        private void updateDataPoints() {
            Group plotContent = (Group) lookup(".plot-content");
            seriesGap.forEach((seriesNo, gapIndexes) -> {
                // Remove all data points at the  gap indexes
                gapIndexes.forEach(i -> {
                    Node n = lookup(".series" + seriesNo + ".data" + i);
                    if (n != null) {
                        plotContent.getChildren().remove(n);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example, but I will have a problem with this implementation because I'm drawing the charts in real time.

Comment: curious: why would real-time or not make a difference?

Comment: As @kleopatra mentioned, i too did'nt get the difference. In real time, instead of adding a null valve, you will add some random value and store the index in the list.

Comment: I'm begginer in Java FX and I have a problem with adding this custom control to the .fxml file of the parent TabPane control. I have created the chart custom control class based on the code given above, without creating the .fxml file for this custom control. In the TabPane .fxml file I have added the properly import but I have an error  "Unresolved class CustomChartControl" in the .fxml GUI editor. Should I also add "scenebuilder-classpath-element" in the TabPane .fxml and if so which path for NetBeans should be given?

Comment: Have you also included the 'import' declaration in the fxml? You need to include along with all the other imports.. something like `import path.to.CustomChartControl`

Comment: Yes, I have added this import in the TabPane fxml which contains this custom control (only this import) and tried with "scenebuilder-classpath-element" in the TabPane fxml. In the TabPane fxml file I don't have any error but in fxml GUI editor there is "Unresolved class CustomChartControl" and I can't add this control to the TabPane in GUI.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I'm using Gradle project and there is a different "scenebuilder-classpath-element" path?

Comment: I'm using Scene Builder 2.0 and I found that "scenebuilder-classpath-element" is not used in this version ( https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8094986 ) so maybe there is another cause.

Comment: I believe this is a separate issue to the actual OP. Please raise another question, so that someone can identify the issue.

Comment: Because I'm not editing the GUI of the control so the error in th Scene Builder doesn't really matter, but when I have added this custom control, in the `Path path = (Path) lookup(".chart-series-line");` line I have the `null` value. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is that you load the chart without any data..? May be you need to add few null checks in that case?

Comment: Yes, empty data was the reason.

Comment: I think that in line `LineTo lt = (LineTo) path.getElements().get(i + 1);` there will be always out of range. Am I right?

Comment: I have one more question - is it possible to use this algorithm for multiple series in one chart?

Comment: I think you can do that with multiple series as well. Regarding out of range.. it depends on where you want the break. In my demo, it always assumes that the break is not the first or last points. In that case, it will not have index outofbound issues. May be there might be other cases where you need to do some checks. You may need to tackle with different corner cases. I will try to see if i can update my demo for multiple series.

Comment: Yes, I need to tackle with corner case when the break is the last point, because I'm drawing points in real time and I have always the case when the break occurs in the last point. I would be very grateful for an example for multiple series. Thanks.

Comment: I have modified my algorithm, so now when I'm receiving empty values then I'm saving them to the table and adding to the chart when the next not empty value is received - your algorithm works properly. I don't know how to implement multiple series yet.

Comment: Updated the code for multiple series. The key thing is about how we access the nodes using style classes. Each path will have the style class ".chart-series-line" and also its series no like ".series0" , "series1"... So to get each series you can concate styleclasses like ".chart-series-line.series0" & ".chart-series-line.series1". Same with data points as well.

Comment: Your updated code for multiple series works perfectly. Thanks a lot for Your help.

Comment: I have analyzed the algorithm once again and I have noticed that the line `int dataSize = getData().get(0).getData().size();` should be changed to the `int dataSize = getData().get(seriesNo).getData().size();`. In my case when the series data have different length this was a problem.

Comment: Oh yes...you are right.. I overlooked that one.