# simple chat application using Socket

Tags: java, swing, sockets, java-threads

I am trying to create a simple chat application want to send a message from one client to another/ or between client and server however my message is not being sent.
I am not sure about the port(8080) here as well as I copied from the internet.
could anyone please help me what I am doing wrong?
[image]
Client.java
Main

```
  {
   con = new Socket("192.168.0.1", 8080);
     while (true) {
        try {
            
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            String string = input.readUTF();
            textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n" + "Server: " + string);
        } catch (Exception ev) {
             textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+" \n" +"Network issues ");

             try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        
            

    }
```

}

```
 private void btnNewButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    if (textField.getText().equals("")) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You cannot send an empty message!");
            }else  {
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n" + "Client : " + textField.getText());
    try {
                    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                    output.writeUTF(textField.getText());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n " + " Network issues");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        System.exit(0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                textField.setText("");
            }
```

Server.Java

```
private  void serverConnection() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Test");
    server = new ServerSocket(8080);
    
     con = server.accept();
     lblNewLabel_2.setText("Client found !");
        lblNewLabel_2.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
     while (true) {
        try {
            
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            String string = input.readUTF();
            textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n " + "Client: " + string);
                            System.out.println(string);
        } catch (Exception ev) {
             textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+" \n" +"Network issues ");
             
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So, my immediate observation is, Swing is not thread safe and is single threaded.  So this means, you should not be updating the UI out of the context of the event dispatching thread and you should not be running any long running or blocking operations from within the EDT.  A `SwingWorker` would be a better over all solution

Comment: You probably want to send chat thru a chat server to manage the connections. A P2P chat, in my opinion, is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Swing is not thread and is single threaded.

This means that you should not update the UI (or some state the UI depends on) from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread and you should not perform any long running or blocking operations from within the context of the EDT.

Start by having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

Once solution might be to use a `SwingWorker`.  This allows you to perform long running or blocking operations within the context of their own threads, but provides a simple way to signal to the UI that changes have occurred safely. See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details.

The following is a VERY basic example.  It's self contained, so the the code can act as either the client or server.  This is tied to `localhost`, so you will need to run two instances locally.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private ReadMessageWorker readWorker;

        private DataInputStream inputStream;
        private DataOutputStream outputStream;

        private ServerSocket serverSocket;
        private Socket socket;

        private JTextField messageField;
        private JTextArea messageArea;

        private JButton startServerButton;
        private JButton startClientButton;
        private JButton shutDownButton;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            messageField = new JTextField(10);
            messageArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);

            messageField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        String text = messageField.getText();
                        outputStream.writeUTF(text);
                        appendMessage(text);
                        messageField.setText(null);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Could not send message", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });

            add(new JScrollPane(messageArea));
            add(messageField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            startServerButton = new JButton("Start server");
            startClientButton = new JButton("Start client");
            shutDownButton = new JButton("Shutdown");
            shutDownButton.setEnabled(false);

            JPanel actionsPanel = new JPanel();
            actionsPanel.add(startServerButton);
            actionsPanel.add(startClientButton);
            actionsPanel.add(shutDownButton);

            add(actionsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            startServerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            createServer();
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            });
            startClientButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            createClient();
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            });
            shutDownButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    shutdown();
                }
            });
        }

        protected void didStartServer() {
            if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        didStartServer();
                    }
                });
                return;
            }

            startServerButton.setEnabled(false);
            startClientButton.setEnabled(false);
            shutDownButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

        protected void didStartClient() {
            if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        didStartClient();
                    }
                });
                return;
            }
            startServerButton.setEnabled(false);
            startClientButton.setEnabled(false);
            shutDownButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

        protected void didShutdown() {
            if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        didShutdown();
                    }
                });
                return;
            }
            startServerButton.setEnabled(true);
            startClientButton.setEnabled(true);
            shutDownButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        protected void createClient() {
            try {
                didStartClient();
                appendMessage("Connecting to server");
                socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
                inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                appendMessage("Connected to server\n");
                createMessageWorker();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Could not create client socket", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        protected void createServer() {
            try {
                didStartServer();
                appendMessage("Starting server");
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
                appendMessage("Waiting for client");
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                appendMessage("Client connected client\n");
                inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                createMessageWorker();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Could not create server socket", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        protected void createMessageWorker() {
            readWorker = new ReadMessageWorker(inputStream, new ReadMessageWorker.MessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void didRecieveMessage(String message) {
                    appendMessage(message);
                }
            });
            readWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println(readWorker.getState());
                    if (readWorker.getState() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                        try {
                            readWorker.get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Stopped reading due to error", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                        shutdown();
                    }
                }
            });
            readWorker.execute();
        }

        protected void appendMessage(String message) {
            if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        appendMessage(message);
                    }
                });
                return;
            }
            messageArea.append(message + "\n");
        }

        protected void shutdown() {
            shutdownServer();
            shutdownSocket();
            appendMessage("\nShutdown completed\n");
            didShutdown();
        }

        protected void shutdownSocket() {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }

        protected void shutdownServer() {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
            if (serverSocket != null) {
                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class ReadMessageWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

        public interface MessageListener {

            public void didRecieveMessage(String message);
        }

        private DataInputStream dataInputStream;
        private AtomicBoolean continueReading;
        private MessageListener listener;

        public ReadMessageWorker(DataInputStream dataInputStream, MessageListener listener) {
            this.dataInputStream = dataInputStream;
            this.listener = listener;
            continueReading = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String message : chunks) {
                listener.didRecieveMessage(message);
            }
        }

        public void stopReading() {
            continueReading.set(false);
            try {
                dataInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            while (continueReading.get()) {
                String text = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                publish(text);
            }

            System.out.println("Read is now down...");

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Further enhancements might include setting up two `SwingWorker`s, one acting as the server and one acting as the client.  This would encapsulate the functionality of the `createXxx` methods.

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer